# Coded UI Test Selenium Chrome Driver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium chromedriver;

```
The open chrome driver window displays:
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.8.241075) on port 10820
[8804:7492:0110/155544:ERROR:chrome_views_delegate.cc(176)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[8804:7492:0110/155544:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[8804:7492:0110/155544:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED


Windows 8
ChromeDriver 2.8
Selenium 2.39
Chrome version 32.0.1700.102 m
```

Coded UI Test;

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";
var browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
...
```

Comment: The question is what? What's the problem here?

Comment: I wrote the errors, it doesn't work, if you look question you can see it

Comment: There is no question. You've given us a piece of code and not told us what is wrong with it.

Comment: Its surprising that we got 4 answers even without getting the question.

Answer (score 0):

To run a chrome driver refer below code.
You can download the driver from 
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Step 1 :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverPath+"\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Step 2

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(YOUR_URL_HERE)
```

Comment: I use Visual Studio(C#), How does it run?

Comment: Check this url . It should help. http://www.joecolantonio.com/2013/01/18/selenium-webdriver-using-chrome-webdriver-in-visual-studio-c/

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you have to write following code:

```
IWebDriver  driver = new ChromeDriver("fullpath to chrome driver exe");   
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

You can download the Chrome Driver from this URL:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score -2):

Change the url to https://www.google.com.
Right now you are using http://www.google.com

Comment: What difference it makes? For me both goes to https version.